# assign instance variable to a static variable

Tags: java, static

**I have something like this:**

```
public class Test {

    public static MyObject o4All = null;

    public MyObject o4This = null;

    public void initialize() {

        // create an instance of MyObject by constructor
        this.o4This = new MyObject(/* ... */);

        // this works, but I am wondering
        // how o4All is internally created (call by value/reference?)
        Test.o4All = this.o4This;

    }
}
```

I know, I should assign or change a static variable only by a static method. But according  to java-docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), I can use an object reference.

> Class methods **cannot** access instance variables or instance methods
>   directly—they must use an object reference.

What if I change a property of o4This? Will the property of o4All also be changed indirectly?

Comment: You don't assign a *variable* to a variable, but rather an object reference to a variable. That's a big difference and understanding this will help you understand the behavior of your program and Rohit Jain's advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What if I change a property of o4This? Will the property of o4All also
>   be changed indirectly?

**Yes**, it will be changed. Because now, both `o4All` and `o4This` are referring to the same instance. You did this by the following assignment: -

```
Test.o4All = this.o4This;
```

In the above assignment, you are not creating a copy of the instance referred to by `o4This`, rather, you are just copying the value of `o4This` in the `o4All` reference. Now, since `o4This` value is a reference to some `instance`. So, `o4All` now have reference to the same instance as that of `o4This`. And hence, any change you make to the `instance` using a reference, will be reflected in the other reference too.